# Controlling an Electric Ducted Fan via a Raspberry Pi

Tags: electronics

How could I connect an EDF to a raspberry pi to control importantly On/Off, and if possible the power supplied to it? The information for the specific EDF is

- Working Voltage:  3s-4s
- Motor :  Brushless Motor 2839     2600kv
- Maximum Current: 35-49A
- Thrust: 1.1-1.4kg

and the battery is already sorted out.

Comment: This really isn't the correct place for this question.  The Pi is pretty irrelevant to any answer.

Comment: Can it not be controlled by the GPIO pins, or are you just saying that the requisites will be the same if it's an arduino/etc.?

Comment: The Pi's GPIO are all 3V3 as are many other micros and some Arduinos.  That will be pretty irrelevant to any solution.

Comment: "s" is not a unit of voltage.

Comment: @JayEye s is commonly used for lipos to indicate the number of cells, so s is roughly 4V.

Comment: I'll stick to SI units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution to drive brushless motors is to use an ESC.

ESCs are controlled in a similar way to servos.

Send 1000 µs pulses for off, 2000 µs pulses for full throttle, and vary the speed using the intermediate values.

The Pi can generate the needed ESC control pulses from (any of) its GPIO.